# Convert Count ... Group By From SQL Query To LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

Please help me convert the MSSQL below to LINQ.

```
SELECT A.id, A.type, COUNT(IIf(B.BookId IS NOT NULL, 0, null)) AS TotalCount
FROM Store A
LEFT JOIN Book B ON A.id = B.id
GROUP BY A.id, A.type;
```

I currently have this LINQ code:

```
from a in Store
join b in Book on a.id equals b.id into c
from d in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
group a by new
{
    a.id,
    a.type
} into g 
select new
{
    StoreId = g.Key.id,
    StoreType = g.Key.type,
    TotalCount = g.Key !=null?g.Count():0
}
```

I think I'm missing something important.

Comment: Please describe the issue with your LINQ query in more detail. Does your query compile? If it compiles what happens when it executes? If not, what is the error?

Comment: Hi, welcome at StackOverflow. To get the most out of StackOverflow, please pay close attention to your question _right after_ asking it. Most questions get most views in the first few minutes. So if someone asks for clarification _be quick_ to provide it by editing your post, otherwise people will lose interest and move on.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. There's nothing wrong with my LINQ query but that's not my expected result. However, **D Stanley** has been pointed out the problem. Thanks you everone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not trying to extract any values from the `Book` part of the join you don't need `DefaultIfEmpty()`, and since the join is a "group join" as a result of the `into` clause you don't need to group again:

```
from a in Store
join b in Book on a.id equals b.id into c
select new
{
    StoreId = a.id,
    StoreType = a.type,
    TotalCount = C.Count()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, u save me for a day. If i want to add in a WHERE CLAUSE like this - `WHERE (B.RackId = 4 OR B.RackId IS null)` then how to do it on LINQ. I'm new to LINQ, that's why i'm not so understand the infrastructure & concept of the LINQ. Do u have any recommended article or tutorial for me??

Comment: ok, I found the answer - SQL Query `WHERE (B.RackId = 4 OR B.RackId IS null)`   LINQ query `TotalCount = c.Count(e => e.RackId == 4 || e.RackId == null)`